# mcrypt isn't loading on MAC

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mcrypt

I have manually installed PHP on my mac which is running lion. I installed mcrypt as well. It was working fine until few days ago it stopped working (didn't load). Most probably this happened after the latest software update.

Now I am trying to install mcrypt again. I tried everything I could and followed most of the tutorials online. No luck yet.

Here is what I have done.

1. downloaded libmcrypt
2. configured and installed it.

I am running php 5.4.7

1. I downloaded the source. went to mcrypt folder and phpize.
2. configured and installed.
3. Edited the php.ini to add extension = mycrypt.so. Even tried putting the path in extension_dir.
4. restarted Apache. still doesn't work.

I have now spent days figuring this out but still cant work it out. I am in point where I am thinking of doing a clean install :(

These are the few things I have noticed that are wierd and may be the reason of problem.

When I do phpize this is what I get

```
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20090626
Zend Module Api No:      20090626
Zend Extension Api No:   220090626
```

but when it finishes installing it gives me path to

```
/usr/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20100525/
```

Any help will be really appreciated. If you need any help I will provide any necessary details.

Comment: Any entries in the log files?

Comment: here is the copy of log. https://dl.dropbox.com/u/3230707/error_log